# Target="_self" not reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have my angular directive, and that is some div's with around it an `<a href="" target="_self"></a>` but when I click on the div it doesn't reload my page.

Am I doing something wrong?

This is the full directive

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l4">
    <div class="video-card">
        <a href="#/videos/detail/{{video.Id}}" target="_self">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img ng-src="{{video.ThumbnailUrl?video.ThumbnailUrl:'img/images.png'}}" src="" />
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#/videos/detail/{{video.Id}}" target="_self">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-title-box">
                    <a href="#/videos/detail/{{video.Id}}">
                        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">
                            {{video.Title}}
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <div class="more-info">
                        <span class="group grey-text">
                            {{ video.Author}}
                        </span>
                        <a href="#/groups/detail/{{playlist.Id}}/List/{{video.Id}}" ng-if="playlist">
                            <i class="mdi-av-play-arrow right tooltipped black-text small "
                               data-position="top" data-delay="0" data-tooltip="{{'video.playFromhere' | translate}}"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to reload the page due to a bug in a plugin I'm using on the detail page, and nor the author of that plugin nor I can figure out what is happening, and the only way to get it work is to reload the page when going to a video.

Comment: Look up `$route.reload();` this will do what you want

Comment: Try using `target="_parent"` or `target="_top"`. However, do you have any JS code linked to that action? Is there a `return false` or a `preventDefault()` behaviour attached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reload a page in Javascript using `window.location.reload()`

```
<a href="" onclick="window.location.reload()"></a>
```

Comment: As note, you can use `.reload(true)` to get new contents from server (witouth cache) and `.reload(false)` to get cached contents

Comment: It's not working for IE11. Any other way to do for IE11?

Comment: @SurendraJnawali If `reload()` is not defined (when using IE), you can define the reload function and put `window.location=window.location` inside it. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Target only sets which frame the link should act on. So if you want the document to reload use

```
window.location.reload();
```